# How to scale a view without CGAffineTransform

Tags: iphone, ios, cgaffinetransform

I need to scale a view with UIPinchGestureRecognizer but without CGAffineTransform,
so how to change this code to do it without CGAffineTransform?

```
- (IBAction)zoomma:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender scale];
    if (factor > 1) {
        self.sgungaView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor + (factor-1), lastScaleFactor + (factor-1));
    } else {
        self.sgungaView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(lastScaleFactor * factor, lastScaleFactor * factor);
    }

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) { 
        if (factor > 1) {
            lastScaleFactor += (factor-1); 
        } else {
            lastScaleFactor *= factor;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Not a masterpiece but this works

```
- (void)zoomma:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGFloat factor = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender scale];
    if (factor > 1) {
        float enlarge = lastScaleFactor + (factor-1);
        [self.sgungaView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.sgungaView.bounds.size.height + enlarge, self.sgungaView.bounds.size.height + enlarge)];
    } else {
        float stringi = lastScaleFactor * factor;
        [self.sgungaView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.sgungaView.bounds.size.height - stringi, self.sgungaView.bounds.size.height - stringi)];
    }

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) { 
        if (factor > 1) {
            lastScaleFactor += (factor-1); 
        } else {
            lastScaleFactor *= factor;
        }
    }
}
```

there's a better way?

Comment: Why do you not want to use CGAffineTransform?

Comment: I have a method that apply a rotation on that view and I can't concat the transforms

Comment: Why can't you concatenate the 2 transforms?

Comment: a solution can be a way to make permanent the transform, but looks like there's no way to do it

Comment: I can't concatenate because the rotation transform is driven by the device rotation, I tried to do it without luck

Comment: You need to concatenate the transforms. I'll post code when I get home two days. If others want to answer using this method, then go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an UIScrollView to your view and add your elements (the elements of your view) to the UIScrollView. Then you can use the zoom delegete from UIScrollView to zoom.

This works well for me.

Comment: This is wrong. You are wasting resources using a UIScrollView for this. You need to concatenate the transforms.